# Expression Expected not sure where I went wrong

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a roman numberal converter.  I can not seem to get the program to function properly as I am getting the expression expected error.  I have fixed most of these but the last two are eluding me.  Please help to figuare this out.  I am using Visual Basic 2013.  Here is the code that I have so far.

```
'Get the input from the user and test to see it is an integer.
    If Integer.TryParse (txtUserInput.Text, CInt(intUserNumber), Then
    'Display the Roman Numeral.
    Select Case (CStr(intUserNumber()))
        Case CStr(1)
            lblRomanNumeral.Text = "I"
        Case CStr(2)
            lblRomanNumeral.Text = "II"
        Case CStr(3)
            lblRomanNumeral.Text = "III"
        Case CStr(4)
            lblRomanNumeral.Text = "IV"
        Case CStr(5)
            lblRomanNumeral.Text = "V"
        Case CStr(6)
            lblRomanNumeral.Text = "VI"
        Case CStr(7)
            lblRomanNumeral.Text = "VII"
        Case CStr(8)
            lblRomanNumeral.Text = "VIII"
        Case CStr(9)
            lblRomanNumeral.Text = "IX"
        Case CStr(10)
            lblRomanNumeral.Text = "X"
    End Select

    If
        lblRomanNumeral.Text = "Not an integer"
    Else

    End If

    End


End Sub
```

Comment: there is a lot of unneeded conversions...string to int back to string and another string conversion for the Case statement.  `CInt(intUserNumber)` isnt needed if it is an Int32 var.

Comment: Why is there a comma at the end of your `CInt(intUserNumber), `? That is causing the `expression expected` error. But there are more problems with your code. e.g. your 2nd IF is missing the condition and THEN.

Answer (score 1):

The `Expression Expected` error is due to the extra comma at the end of your first IF statement.

```
If Integer.TryParse (txtUserInput.Text, CInt(intUserNumber), <-- this comma
```

There are other errors too in your code. e.g. your 2nd IF statement is missing the condition and the THEN keyword etc. You also have a lot of unnecessary conversions from String to Integer and vice-versa.

But coming back to your program, you don't need that long series of `SELECT CASE` statements at all. That can be done in one line using the `Choose` function, like this:

```
'Get the input from the user and test to see it is an integer.
If Integer.TryParse(txtUserInput.Text, intUserNumber) Then
    'Display the Roman Numeral.
    Select Case intUserNumber
        Case 1 To 10
            lblRomanNumeral.Text = Choose(intUserNumber, "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X").ToString
        Case Else
            lblRomanNumeral.Text = "integer value out of range!"
    End Select
Else
    lblRomanNumeral.Text = "Not an integer"
End If
```

HTH.